# Any way to update a ManyToMany field via a queryset?

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

Suppose I have an object:

```
survey = Survey.objects.all().first()
```

and I want to create a relationship between it and a group of objects:

```
respondents = Respondent.objects.all()

for r in respondents:
    r.eligible_for.add(survey)
```

where `eligible_for` is an M2M field in the `Respondent` model.

Is there any way to do it in one pass, or do I need to loop over the queryset?

**models.py**

```
class Questionnaire(models.Model):
    label = models.CharField(max_length=48)
    organization = models.ForeignKey('Home.Organization', on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=True)

class Respondent(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField('Home.ListenUser', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    organization = models.ForeignKey('Home.Organization', on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    eligible_for = models.ManyToManyField('Questionnaire', related_name='eligible_users', blank=True)
```

Comment: What is the `related_name` of the relation? Can you share relevant parts of your models?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/relations/

`survey.eligible_users.set(respondents)` is another way to do this without having to unpack the list.

Answer (score 6):

[**`.add(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/relations/#django.db.models.fields.related.RelatedManager.add) can take a variable number of items, and will usually add these in bulk.

You can thus add all the `r`s with:

```
survey.eligible_users.add(*respondents)
```

We here thus add the `respondents` to the relation in reverse. Notice the asterisk (`*`) in front of `respondents` that will thus perform *iterable unpacking*.

Comment: @AdamStarrh: yes, sorry, somehow I mixed up some variable names :)